# Using a mathematical formula to define player speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm making simple game in which the player is moved by adding force to him. However, I don't want his acceleration to be constant - I want it to vary depending on the current speed. I made simple acceleration script to do this but it doesn't achieve the desired effect:

```
float acceleration
{
    get { return speed/inversedAcceleration; }
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
    if (speed < maxSpeed)
        speed += acceleration * Time.deltaTime;    
}
```

New way that I also tried:

```
float timer = 1.0f;

public float velocity { get { return Mathf.Sqrt(timer)*10; } }

void FixedUpdate()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * velocity);
}
```

The logic is a bit convoluted, because I have experimented unsuccessfully with it for a while. Now, I think I should change it to use the mathematical formula `f(x)=sqrt(x)` as a model for my velocity, rather than my current one which is some form of rational function. How can I change the code to do this, while still using `AddForce()` so the player will correctly interact physically with other objects?

Comment: Uhm...I'm a little confused with what you're doing here. Why are you using speed with `AddForce()`, rather than something like acceleration * mass? Why are you mixing `AddForce()` with your own acceleration implementation? In what ways is your script not what you wanted?

Comment: @Serlite I know it's a bit complicated but I just modified this script many times and variable names are wrong. `speed` is set at the start and its growing until it reaches `maxSpeed`, its not controlling the real speed of the player. I'm using `Addforce()` because I want player to slow down when he hits something etc.

Comment: I feel like you may be using the physics system incorrectly here. A more accurate representation of a rigidbody's speed is `velocity.magnitude`. You can compare that against `maxSpeed` to determine whether more force should still be added - there's no need to manually keep track of a `speed` variable.

Comment: @Serlite Ok thanks, I will use `velocity.magnitude` but how can I use this mathematical formula f(x)=sqrt(x) to change its velocity?

Comment: In what way do you plan on using a square root function? Do you want acceleration to vary based on the current speed's difference from the target speed?

Comment: @Serlite No, I just want velocity to be defined by sqrt function.

Comment: Well, in that case, take the derivative of the function you want to define the velocity, and use it to calculate the acceleration for any given velocity.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like this put into an answer, and I'll find some time to write one up. The problem will be twofold: determining the function that would model the velocity (with `maxspeed` at the asymptote on the y-axis), and then derive it to determine the function that will model the acceleration.

Comment: @Serlite That would be great. I'm trying to do it by myself but with no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, my first suggestion would be to avoid manually tracking the speed of an object - Unity's physics system makes this easy to access accurately, through `Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude`. You can use this to compare against `maxSpeed`, to determine whether additional force should be added or not.

Regarding your desire to have velocity match the curve of `f(x)=sqrt(x)`, you're going to need to do some basic calculus for this. Since you don't want to constrain velocity artificially (because you still want physical interactions to occur), you should instead constrain acceleration to a function.

To determine the function to define the player's acceleration, you'll need to derive the function you want velocity to (ideally) match. This will give you the rate of change of the velocity at any given point - which, by definition, is the acceleration.

So let's say we use the function `f(x)=sqrt(x)` as a model for the ideal velocity. The derivative of `sqrt(x)` is `1/(2 * sqrt(x))` - so this is the function that defines our acceleration. Now, we need to be able to determine the acceleration for any given velocity, since this is the relationship we'll be using in the code. This takes a little simple algebra - we'll need to solve for `x` given `y`:

```
          y = 1/(2 * sqrt(x))
sqrt(x) * y = 1 / 2
    sqrt(x) = 1 / (2 * y)
          x = (1 / (2 * y))^2
```

Now we have an equation that provides us with the required acceleration for any given speed. We can now put this into code - accelerating according to the square root function up to `maxSpeed`:

```
float maxAcceleration = 10;

// Basically x = (1 / (2 * y))^2, but in code
float CalculateAccGivenSpeed(float speed)
{
    // Early exit so we don't bother with undefined results from dividing by 0
    if (speed == 0)
    {
        return Mathf.Infinity;
    }

    float rootAcc = 1 / (2 * speed);
    return rootAcc * rootAcc;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Only accelerate if speed is lower than maximum allowed
    if (rb.velocity.magnitude < maxSpeed)
    {
        float allowableAcc = CalculateAccGivenSpeed(rb.velocity.magnitude);

        // Constrain acceleration here so rigidbody doesn't explode from stationary
        allowableAcc = Mathf.Min(maxAcceleration, allowableAcc);

        // Using ForceMode.Acceleration so we don't have to worry about mass
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * allowableAcc, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
}
```

If you find the acceleration goes too quickly/slowly, you can multiply the result of `CalculateAccGivenSpeed()` with a scalar value. Mathematically, this will scale the square root function along the y-axis, preserving the square root relationship, but changing the rate at which is reaches a given y-value (speed).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow thanks for your detailed anserw! I understand idea of the script, but I can't test it right now. I will as soon as I will come back home.

Comment: No problem - at the very least, I hope this sets you on the right direction!

Comment: I tested this script and there is one problem. If i set drag of the object to more than 0 the velocity stops at a certain value, no matter how many times I multiply the result of `CalculateAccGivenSpeed()`. For example for drag set to 1 velocity stops at about 4.031. Do you know what might fix this issue? Mayby changing mathematical formula?

Comment: @faken Drag makes the problem a little more complicated. What you'd do in this case is calculate a factor to multiply your acceleration by based on the target velocity you want, using the [equation given here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/terminal-velocity.34667/). (Solve for `maxAcceleration`, and divide it by the acceleration at that velocity using `CalculateAccGivenSpeed()`.) Let me know if you have any questions about that, or need help implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to keep all the physics formulae consistent (reinventing kinematics is tricky), one physics solution could be to make an objects mass a function of its velocity (e.g. `m=m_0+k*v^2` to get something like you sqrt approach).

As a result, a force `F=ma` will result in a lower acceleration when an object is more massive (i.e. is travelling faster).

Sound familiar-ish? Well that's what `E=mc^2` means for objects travelling very fast. I don't recommend implementing other relativistic effects however.

Comment: I don't think that changing objects mass is good solution, because it performs other actions (like jumping) and it might break everything else. I tried something else (you can see it in question), can you check if it is ok?

Comment: @faken, how are you implementing 3d speeds/accelerations/forces with scalar values?

Comment: What do you think about script which I added to my question. Isn't it god enough? Or does it have some bugs?